# How to get access token for Particle photon in Local cloud mode

Tags: node.js, particle-photon

I followed [this](https://github.com/particle-iot/spark-server) tutorial to setup `spark-server` to use with `Particle Photon`, locally. After setting everything up, as instructed, I managed to read from the `core` and the server console displayed this message:

```
Your server IP address is: 10.0.0.10
server started { host: 'localhost', port: 5683 }
Connection from: 10.0.0.9, connId: 1
on ready { coreID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  ip: '10.0.0.9',
  product_id: 6,
  firmware_version: 65535,
  cache_key: '_0' }
Core online!
```

But when I try to access the `API` like this (Using `POSTMAN`)

```
GET http://10.0.0.10:8080/v1/devices
```

It returns a status 400, like this

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The access token was not found"
}
```

How do I get the access token, to be used with the local cloud? I tried using the token present in `.json` files inside `.particle` folder, but it says invalid token. I could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to obtain the Particle Cloud Access Token from the console, but they removed that option and now you must do it through the CLI. https://docs.particle.io/reference/developer-tools/cli/#particle-token-list